# password checking jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, password-protection

i am searching for a password strenght checking jQuery plugin.

i found this one: http://shouvik.net/pwdmeter.php

but it seems it doesn't work with jQuery 1.4.3.

can you guide me?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying out my plugin. I just tried my plugin with jquery v1.4.4 and it seems to be working fine for me. Can you please upload your code somewhere and give me the link so that I can see what are you missing? Thanks
Shouvik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a bunch of scripts :)

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-password-strength-meter-scripts-for-a-better-registration-interface/

Comment: thanks,the one i mentioned above is really nice,it is ok with jquery(1.4.3).my fault was something else.

Answer (score 1):

The best: [nakedpassword](http://www.nakedpassword.com/).